# StrictNullChecks vs Union Types via syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, types, union-types

### [StrictNullChecks](https://scotch.io/tutorials/5-features-to-watch-out-for-in-angular-4#3-typescripts-strictnullchecks)

> Originally, null and undefined are JavaScript valid first class type citizens. TypeScript before now didn't adhere to that, which means you can't define a variable and tell TypeScript that this variable's value can be null or undefined.

**Syntax**

```
let y: number | null;
let z: number | undefined;
```

### [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

> Union types are closely related to intersection types, but they are used very differently. Occasionally, you’ll run into a library that expects a parameter to be either a number or a string

**Syntax:**

```
function padLeft(value: string | number | boolean) {
// codings
   }
```

---

**My question is:**

- Is it possible to use `StrictNullChecks` concepts within `Union Types` Concept?
  Like,

  ```
     function padLeft(value: string | undefined | number | undefined) { // coding's }
  ```

---

- Is it possible to use `strictnullcheck` in function parameters?
  like,

  ```
             function padLeft(value: string | undefined) { // coding's }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, except that `string | undefined | number | undefined` has one `undefined` too many.

Comment: Which one is possible ? first question or second question. Can you share more details with code? because it's should be helps others.

Comment: Both are possible with the exception I mentioned. In the first case it should be `string | number | undefined`, meaning `value` can be of type string, number or undefined when calling padLeft. In the second case it can only be string or undefined. If you attept to call padLeft with any other type (eg. a number in the second case), the TypeScript compiler will complain.

Comment: You could add it in the answer.  I'll wait for some other answers for more details